# Django model form cant use two modelforms

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

I was wondering how i can use two `models` in a `modelform`

I tried :

```
from django import forms

from .models import Question, Choice

class CreateQuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
       model = question, choice 
       Fields = [
                    'question'
                    'choice_text
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/) in order to use two different forms in the same.

Firstly, you have to define each form from their models.

Then, you can use `formset_factory` to combine both forms.